# How to conditionally concatenate two table columns in query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
Description    SID        code          
-----------    ----       ---------    
ssdad          1001       S2378797     
gfd            1002               
gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
ssdad          1004       M0007867     
gfd            1005       
gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111
```

How do I concatenate `SID` and `code` to make it `SID-Code`, but if `code` is null, the result should not be like for example `1002-`. Instead it should contain only the `SID` without following `-`.

The result should look like this:

```
Description    SID        code         SID-Code
-----------    ----       ---------    ---------
ssdad          1001       S2378797     1001-S2378797
gfd            1002                    1002
gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     1003-R1165778
ssdad          1004       M0007867     1004-M0007867  
gfd            1005                    1005
gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     1006
```

Comment: What is the concatenation operator in ms access? if it is the same as SQL-Server, you would do `SELECT description, SID, code, sid + '-' + code FROM table` You'll need a CASE condition for '-'

Comment: @abhi If **Code** has null values then it would be eg.1002- . I need to concate with out dash if **Code** has nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access queries you can use a lot of VBA functions. Try this one:

```
SELECT Description, SID, code, IIf(IsNull(code), SID, SID & "-" & code) As [SID-Code]
FROM MyTable
```

Whithin SQL `IIf(code Is NULL, SID, SID & "-" & code)` should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the differences in VBA's two concatenation operators:

Nulls don't propagate using `&`:

"abc" & Null = "abc"

Nulls do propagate using `+`:

"abc" + Null = Null

```
SELECT Description, SID, code, SID & ("-" + code) as [SID-Code])
FROM YourTable
```